# Is it possible to force Scite as topmost window?

Tags: windows, scite

I am using SciTE as text editor. It is possible to run script and see the results in its console output.

The application I am working on is displayed fullscreen and is hiding SciTE.

Is there an option to make SciTE always visible? I am working on Windows.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my SciTE there's "Always On Top" under Options.
I use [Version 1.75 Nov 22 2007 15:38:26 by Neil Hodgson](http://gisdeveloper.tripod.com/scite.html).